Nearest neighbour interpolation with transparency
I'm new to C# and trying to write a program that places two transparent images one on top of the other using Forms.
The pictures are resized using the nearest neighbor interpolation.
The problem is that the other picture simply overlaps the first one. Both of the pictures are the same size and they have transparent backgrounds.
If you plan to edit my code, make sure to keep nearest neighbor interpolation.
namespace MainForm {
    public partial class MainForm : Form {
        private PictureBox pb = new PictureBox() {
            Dock=DockStyle.Fill,
            SizeMode=PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage,
            BackColor=Color.Transparent,
            Visible=true
        };

        private PictureBox pb2 = new PictureBox() {
            Dock=DockStyle.Fill,
            SizeMode=PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage,
            BackColor=Color.Transparent,
            Visible=true
        };

        public MainForm() {
            InitializeComponent();
            icc();
        }

        private void icc() {
            pb.SendToBack();
            pb2.BringToFront();
            this.Controls.Add(pb);
            this.Controls.Add(pb2);
            this.KeyPreview=true;
            this.Load+=MainForm_Load;
        }

        private void MainForm_Load(object sender,EventArgs e) {
            try {
                pb.Image = rs(Image.FromFile("picture1.png"),pb.Width,pb.Height);
            } catch(Exception ex) {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            try {
                pb2.Image = rs(Image.FromFile("picture2.png"),pb2.Width,pb2.Height);
            } catch(Exception ex) {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private Image rs(Image i,int w,int h) {
            Bitmap rsi = new Bitmap(w,h,PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(rsi)) {
                g.Clear(Color.Transparent);
                g.InterpolationMode=InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
                g.PixelOffsetMode=PixelOffsetMode.Half;
                g.CompositingMode=CompositingMode.SourceOver;
                g.DrawImage(i,new Rectangle(0,0,w,h));
            }
            return rsi;
        }
    }
}

I tried using the BackColor=Color.Transparent property but it didn't fix it. Same with g.Clear(Color.Transparent); in the rs function. Also, I tried looking for the answers to this error but came up empty-handed.

You're overlapping two Controls, not two images. Use a (one) PictureBox as canvas (because it's double-buffered by default) and draw the images yourself (using the Paint event of the PictureBox)
